# How can I multiply many small numbers together without getting 0?

Tags: r, math

For example,

```
Reduce("*",rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=.0001))
```

Will typically result in 0. How can I get the actual value of the multiplication operation, no matter how small it is (e.g 1e-10000000)?

Multiplying by a constant is one solution, but I am looking for the actual value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/vignettes/Rmpfr-pkg.pdf

This package should help.  You can define your accuracy.

In case you couldn't figure it out:

```
test <- mpfr(rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=.0001), 240)

Reduce("*", test)
```

Comment: it would add value to include a working code snippet

Comment: thanks @iShouldUseAName for following through. The point is to give functional answers, no need to state the simplicity of things.

Comment: NP @casandra.  Enjoy the arbitrary accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the underflow for some time by adding the logarithms of the numbers instead of multiplying them.

This only works for positive numbers, so you have to split off the signs and keep them in some extra product.

In the end you will have to compute the exponential, there it would be best to first extract the powers of 10 from the sum of logarithms.

But I do not know how to formulate that for reduce.